# Networkx: convert a MultiDiGraph to DiGraph

Tags: python, python-3.x, networkx, graph-theory

Is there a quick method to convert a networkx MultiDiGraph object to DiGraph? I am creating a [scale_free_graph](http://scale_free_graph) using this code:

```
import networkx as nx
G = nx.scale_free_graph(100)
```

But I would like to remove all self loops and parallel edges from my graph.

Answer (score 2):

You can create the new `nx.DiGraph` using the `nx.MultiDiGraph` [as input graph](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/stable/reference/classes/generated/networkx.DiGraph.__init__.html#networkx.DiGraph.__init__):

> `incoming_graph_data` (input graph (optional, default: `None`)) – Data to initialize graph. If `None` (default) an empty graph is created. The data can be an edge list, or any NetworkX graph object. If the corresponding optional Python packages are installed the data can also be a NumPy matrix or 2d ndarray, a SciPy sparse matrix, or a PyGraphviz graph.

```
import networkx as nx

G = nx.MultiDiGraph()
G.add_edges_from([
    (1, 2),
    (1, 2),
    (1, 2)
])
print('G edges:', G.edges)
H = nx.DiGraph(G)
print('H edges:', H.edges)
```

Will print:

> ```
> G edges: [(1, 2, 0), (1, 2, 1), (1, 2, 2)]
> H edges: [(1, 2)]
> ```